# Sum every n columns starting at the 1st column in the range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Excel/Google Sheets I have found how to sum every N columns on websites such as https://exceljet.net/formula/fixed-value-every-n-columns, but the problem is, from what I can see is that it starts at N column each time. I need something that starts from column 1 and then counts every N columns. like the following:

[image]

I need to do this with a formula and not a script.

Answer (score 7):

#### Google sheets formula:

```
=SUM(FILTER(A2:J2, MOD(A2:J2, L2)=1))
```

then drag to other cells

[image]

or use this array version:

#### Array version:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(A2:J4,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:J4)^0 * 
 N(MOD(COLUMN(A2:J4), L2:L4)=1)))), ,1)
```

[image]

If you want the cells that were added to be automatically highlighted.

**Conditional formatting used on `A2:J`:**

```
=MOD(COLUMN(), $L2)=1
```

Comment: incredibly elegant and efficient (first one)!

Comment: I'd say first one should be like: =SUM(FILTER(B2:AE2, MOD(column(B2:AE2), 2)=1))

Answer (score 4):

With Google-Sheets, try:

[image]

Formula in `M2`:

```
=SUM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:J2),"Skipping "&L2))
```

---

Or, a single dynamic array formula (without dragging):

```
=INDEX(MMULT(A2:J4*(MOD(COLUMN(A2:J4),L2:L4)=1),SEQUENCE(10,1,1,0)))
```

Or, more dynamic:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(A2:J4*(MOD(COLUMN(A2:J4),L2:L4)=1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A2:J4),1,1,0)))
```

---

**Note**: The latter would also work in Excel with slight modifications.

Answer (score 3):

In M2:

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:J2,N(MOD(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A2:J2),0),L2)=0))`

and copied down.

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula on column M:

```
=SUM((sumif(ArrayFormula(mod((COLUMN(B2:J2)-COLUMN(B2)+1),L2)),0,B2:J2))+A2)
```

Here's the result on **Column M**.
[image]

Just to break down the code `sumif(ArrayFormula(mod((COLUMN(B2:J2)-COLUMN(B2)+1),L2)),0,B2:J2)` does the actual calculation with the number of intervals set on **Column L** but take note that I started at the *2nd column* so the range here does not include the first column. The result from this is at the **Column O** highlighted red as you can see in the screenshot.

At the **Column M** is the actual solution where I only added the first column by using SUM on top of the previous formula.

I hope my explanation is clear.

Just copy/drag the formula down to each row and it should work.

Reference: [How to Sum Every Nth Row or Column in Google Sheets Using SUMIF](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-sum-every-nth-row-in-google-sheets/#:%7E:text=With%20SUMIF%20function%20you%20can,of%20any%20specific%20row%20numbers.)